# How do I properly format this API call?

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am making a telegram chatbot and can't figure out how to take out the `[{'` from the output.

```
def tether(bot, update):
    tetherCall = "https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/property/31"
    tetherCallJson = requests.get(tetherCall).json()
    tetherOut = tetherCallJson ['issuances'][:1]
    update.message.reply_text("Last printed tether:  " + str (tetherOut)+" Please take TXID and past it in this block explorer to see more info: https://www.omniexplorer.info/search")
```

My user will see this as a response: `[{'grant': '25000000.00000000', 'txid': 'f307bdf50d90c92278265cd92819c787070d6652ae3c8af46fa6a96278589b03'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a list with a single dict in it:

```
[{'grant': '25000000.00000000',
  'txid': 'f307bdf50d90c92278265cd92819c787070d6652ae3c8af46fa6a96278589b03'}]
```

You should be able to access the dict by indexing the list with `[0]`…

```
tetherOut[0]
# {'grant': '25000000.00000000',
#  'txid': 'f307bdf50d90c92278265cd92819c787070d6652ae3c8af46fa6a96278589b03'}
```

…and if you want to get a particular value from the dict you can index by its name, e.g.

```
tetherOut[0]['txid']
# 'f307bdf50d90c92278265cd92819c787070d6652ae3c8af46fa6a96278589b03'
```

Be careful chaining these things, though. If `tetherOut` is an empty list, `tetherOut[0]` will generate an `IndexError`. You'll probably want to catch that (and the `KeyError` that an invalid dict key will generate).

Comment: thanks! is there a quicker way to format the {} from it or should i define the grant and txid and print both in the same line?

Comment: @toBePythonNinja, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "a quicker way to format the `{}`"?

Comment: i would like to take it out of the dict {} and just print: txid: f307bdf50d90c92278265cd92819c787070d6652ae3c8af46fa6a96278589b03

Comment: @toBePythonNinja, there's no built in way to print a key and value together outside of a dict. But you can include a literal `txid: ` in your string, e.g. `'Last printed tether: txid: '`.